# Restrict access to port forwarding in ssh

Tags: linux, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

Is there a way to restrict access a local port I opened so that only one IP or a range of IPs could access?

Example:

```
ssh IP -L 0.0.0.0:25:DESTINATION:25
```

I opened my local port 25 to another place, I want that only the IP 192.168.1.200 could access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need remote access from one IP address:

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s IP --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

If you changed the port make the changes.